# Sencha Touch: Removing an item then updating view on orientation change etc

Tags: sencha-touch, orientation-changes

thanks for the reply, looks like we might be getting somewhere. I have created a new view thats plain and in a simple form. See below:

```
  var homePanelTop = new Ext.Panel({    id:'topCont',
      cls:'topCont'    
  });
  var homePanelBtm = new Ext.Panel({
      id:'btmCont',
      cls:'btmCont'
  });


  App.views.HomeIndex = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
          id:'mainlayout',
          fullscreen : true,
          layout: {
                      type: 'vbox',
                      align: 'stretch',
              },
              defaults:{flex:1},
           items: [homePanelTop, homePanelBtm],
           suspendLayout: true,
              monitorOrientation: true,
              orientationchange: this.onOrientationChange,
              onOrientationChange: function(orientation, w, h){
                  this.suspendLayout = false;
                   if(orientation === 'portrait'){
                           console.log('P: ' + orientation);
                              this.add(homePanelTop, true);
                          } else {
                           console.log('L: ' + orientation);
                              this.remove(homePanelTop, false);
                      }
                      this.doLayout();
              }
  });
  Ext.reg('HomeIndex', App.views.HomeIndex);
```

What i expect to see with the above view is on first load and portrait, there will be two panels, the top panel(yellow) and a bottom panel (blue). When I rotate as normal I still get the same effect.

But what I am after is that when I rotate to landscape the top panel (yellow) is removed and the bottom panel (blue) fills the rest of the space.

Then when I rotate back to portrait I get both panels back at their design sizes (flex:1)

Whats happening using the code above (testing in chrome) is that the top panel (yellow) remains at the top but slightly smaller in height and does not disappear like it should

Anyway notice the two console trace commands I have and these are showing the following readings on rotation:

**After first load, I then rotate to landscape and the output is:**

L: landscape

L: landscape

Attempted to remove a component that does not exist. Ext.Container: remove takes an argument of the component to remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

L: landscape

Attempted to remove a component that does not exist. Ext.Container: remove takes an argument of the component to remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

L: landscape

Attempted to remove a component that does not exist. Ext.Container: remove takes an argument of the component to remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

**The when I rotate back to portrait I get the following output:**

L: landscape

Attempted to remove a component that does not exist. Ext.Container: remove takes an argument of the component to remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

L: landscape

Attempted to remove a component that does not exist. Ext.Container: remove takes an argument 
of the component to remove. cmp.remove() is incorrect usage.

P: portrait

P: portrait

So looking at this on the lanscape rotation it actually some how fires the **onorientationchange** function 4 times, the first one is ok the other three with an error as the first one already removed it so thats what the warnings are for I believe.

Then with the portrait ones I get two registering as lanscape calls then two hits registering portrait calls.

All this with one movement, so is this somehow causing the remove and add code's not to work as predicted and how to prevent the orientation being called four times on rotation??

If anyone has an idea on the development of this feel free to join in.

Thanks for the help so far
Si

Answer (score 0):

Many years later... and more for someone like me that stumbles on to this looking for help.

Two things.

1) The message "Attempted to remove a component that does not exist" is found only in the "development" version of the ExtJS library and I don't know that it is a reliable indicator of a problem.

2) If you can upgrade to ExtJS 4.1x.  It will give you access to better debugging tools.  I am thinking specifically of the 'Ext JS Page Analyzer'.  This will help you see what the layout engine is doing as apposed to what you hope it is doing.

See:  http://www.sencha.com/blog/optimizing-ext-js-4-1-based-applications

Comment: unfortunately i have given up the ghost with sencha, but thank you for the feedback

Comment: I have done enough ExtJS work to understand where some of your frustrations might come from.  It is definitely a different beast then jQuery or any other library like that.

Comment: yeah! I have moved on to one like Emberjs and Angularjs :-)